# Determine whether or not each of the following series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine whether or not each of the following series is convergent
a) $\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{ncos(n\pi)}{n+1}$
$b) \sum_n^{\infty} (n + \frac{1}{n})$($n^6$ + ln $n$$)^{-1/2}$

For a)$\frac{ncos(n\pi)}{n+1}$ can be written as $\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}$ since $cos(n\pi)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. But none of the convergence tests work for the new series. How do I prove it is convergent or divergent?

For b) we have to use the comparison test but not sure with what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first series

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  a_n \neq 0$$

So the series does not converge.  For the second make comparison with the series $$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: Sorry I don't get how for b) the series is less than $1/n^2$